# How to export the images that inside adobe illustrator file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, cs6, save

[image]

Right now I have a AI file, and there are some images used in it , the problem is , how to export all of them? Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be using a legacy version of Illustrator.

In **Illustrator CC** you can highlight embedded images in the **Links Panel** and choose `Unembed...` from the **Links Panel Menu** which will bring up the Save As dialog window allowing you to save the image separately.

[image]

If the image is indeed a link, you would highlight it in the **Links Panel** and choose `Edit original...` to open the original image in the appropriate application.

[image]

This is why I say you are working with an older version if Illustrator. Your Links Panel shows the images as embedded. However, you do not have the options possible in Illustrator CC.

---

If none of the above is possible, then simply drag the .ai file to Photoshop to open it in Photoshop. This *will* rasterize everything. However since you *want* the raster images, it won't make a difference. After its opened, simply crop and save the images you need.

Answer (score 1):

Tested with CC 2020;
One other way to export all resources as files is to export document as SVG. This is not keeping the original file names of course but exports all images as PNGs. Also note that exporting PNGs can take long depending on the image dimensions.

`File > Scripts > SaveDocsAsSVG`